# Notification service extensions not working for iOS with react-native-firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I have added the category to my extension info.plist. Also passing the same category in the payload.
Added Notification Service extension to react-native project iOS native side.

**Extension Plist :-**

```
    <key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UNNotificationExtensionCategory</key>
        <string>ACTION_BUTTON</string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.usernotifications.service</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).NotificationService</string>
</dict>
```

extension bundle id :-

```
myprojectbundleid.extension
```

**Extension code:-**

#import "NotificationService.h"
#import "RNFirebaseMessaging.h"

@interface NotificationService ()

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^contentHandler)(UNNotificationContent *contentToDeliver);
@property (nonatomic, strong) UNMutableNotificationContent *bestAttemptContent;

@end

@implementation NotificationService

- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:   (void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {
  NSLog(@"=======NotificationService");
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
    self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];

    // Modify the notification content here...
    self.bestAttemptContent.title = @"modified title";
   [[FIRMessaging extensionHelper] populateNotificationContent:self.bestAttemptContent withContentHandler:contentHandler];

      self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}

- (void)serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire {
   // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
   // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}

@end
```

**payload**

```
{
"mutable-content" : 1,
   "notification": { 
        "title":"Take score",
        "body": "Take your score",
        "sound": "default",
        "click_action":"ACTION_BUTTON",
        "mutable_content": 1
   },
    "apns":{
      "payload": {
         "aps": {
            "mutable-content": 1,
             "click_action": "ACTION_BUTTON",
             "category": "ACTION_BUTTON"
         }
       }
    },  
    "to":"tokentosend",
    "data":{ 
       "channel_id": "channel_id",
        "title":"You have a new message12",
        "body": "hi",
        "sound": "default"
      }
 }
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Did you found any update on this one as I am also facing the same issue, any help will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your property `mutable-content` must be `mutable_content`. Also remove `self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);` at end of your `@interface NotificationService`.

You must know too that your hierarchy bundle Identifier must be at this format:

```
MainApp=> org.testing.app, Service => org.testing.app.service
```